# Not able to produce output inside image.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload

```
var img = new Image();
var url = "some url "
var value = "old value"

img.onError = function() {
  alert('Cannot load image: "'+som+'"');
};

img.crossOrigin = '';
img.onload = function() {
  // do something
  value = "New value"
};
img.src = som;

alert(value);// pops with "old value"
```

Since i am not getting any change that i have done inside onload function? The result i am storing inside onload function can not be used globally?

Comment: Is your function inside document ready?

Comment: No it's not since it's a small part of mu code

Comment: Place a alert inside img.onload whether its firing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code after `onload` will not wait for it to finish before executing.

```
var value = 'old value';

img.onload = function () { // image did not load yet, still waiting
    // do something
    value = "New value"
};

alert(value); // doesn't care if onload is done or not
```

Since `onload` didn't execute before the `alert()` is shown the value did not change. You need a callback or something similar

```
var value = 'old value';

img.onload = function () {
    // do something
    value = "New value"

    imageLoaded();
};

function imageLoaded() { // or just give the value as parameter
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: if i want to use the results which  will be obtaining inside the img.onload function  to get my final output how can i do that ? Since it can't use return function inside img.onload. Basically i want that after img.onload my next line of code should be executed

Comment: @SomPathak that's what the 2nd code is for in my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ts7/

Comment: could you take a look at the  last comment [link](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/317#issuecomment-49917266)

Comment: @SomPathak I'm not sure what I should be looking for, if you have a question please ask it here or create a new question

Comment: please look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929260/image-on-load-function)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the function inside `img.onload` is executed after alert(value);`.

Timeline:

- `value = "old value";`
- img.onload is set to the function (which is not yet executed)
- `alert(value);`
- image is loaded
- `value = "new value";`

if you type `value` into the browser console after the image has loaded, it should be "new value".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it is expected the `alert` would show "old value" because it executes before the `onload` callback. Thanks to the magic of asynchronous code, the order of execution is outlined below:

```
// 1: Declare variables
var img = new Image();
var url = 'some url';
var value = 'old value';

// 2: Assign callback
img.onload = function () {
  // 4: Update value
  value = 'new value';
};

// 3: Alert value
alert(value);
```

Add a delay to the alert if you don't believe me:

```
// THIS IS BAD CODE. It's just to prove that your callback is executing.
setTimeout(function () {
  alert(value);
}, 10000);
```

As long as your image doesn't take more than 10 seconds to load, this should give you the output you're expecting.